# Another Delphi Invalid Pointer Operation

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

This VCL Form program generates the Invalid Pointer Operation notice:

```
Uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ComCtrls,
  DcadMenu_u;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    MenuTestRichEdit: TRichEdit;
    LoadButton: TButton;
    procedure ButtonLoadClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.ButtonLoadClick(Sender: TObject);
  var
    menu : TDcadMenu;
    item1, item2 : TDcadMenuItem;
    strlist :tstringlist;
    i : integer;
  begin
    menu := tDcadMenu.Create();
    item1 := TDcadMenuItem.create ('Option1', 'Do Option1', false, false, true);
    menu.add (item1);
    item2 := TDcadMenuItem.create ('Option2', 'Do Option2', false, false, true);
    menu.add (item2);
    strlist := tstringlist.Create;
    Try
      For i :=  0 to Menu.Count - 1 DO
        begin
          item1 := menu.Items[i];
          strlist.Add (Item1.lblset + '  |  ' + Item1.lblmsg );
         end;
      Form1.MenuTestRichEdit.Lines := strlist;
    finally
      item1.free;
      item2.Free;
      menu.free;
      strlist.Free;
    end;
  end;
```

The code works fine and generates the item list in the Richedit component.  I suspect I am freeing an object that is already being handled, but not clear on what the cause is specifically.  Can someone explain this?

Comment: You are giving the ownership of item1 and item2 to menu. No need to free those items, since menu.free will take care of that.

Comment: We've no idea what these various types are, but it looks like what Lief says above.

Comment: Assuming these menu classes work anything like the standard VCL menu classes, then it should be safe to manually free the menu items before freeing the menu itself. Owned objects usually remove themselves from their owners when being destroyed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can't see the implementation of `TDcadMenu`, but normally adding items to a class gives the ownership of the items to that class, so there is no need to free the items outside of the class. As @Remy comments, it is normally safe to free them before before freeing the `menu` object, though.

In your code you are reassigning `item1`, and when freeing the items, `Item1` and `Item2` both shares the same instance as `menu.Items[1]`. This means that you have a double free, which gives your invalid pointer notice.

```
item1.free;
item2.Free;  // <- Double free of same instance
```